# What is the reason behind maximum is 900 Byte in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, byte

I just confronted and resolved the issue with index string cannot have more than 900 bytes so when we define them as index we have to specify their lengths. The solution was easy but I cannot understand the reason behind this.

Also, some say length of 255, some other says 450 is the safest.

255 sounds more accurate to me in a sense but still these are not fully clear in my mind.

I would be appreciated if someone can tell me the reason behind 900 bytes per row and is it more accurate to use 255 or 450 length where we talk about strings/chars

Thanks!

Comment: That was a design decision taken by the SQL Server team - I haven't found any clear explanation as to why it is set to 900 bytes - but that really doesn't matter - it's just a hard limit - make sure you stay within in and keep coding!

Comment: Of course! I will stay in it. After all, it is a bound. I just wondered why 900 but apparently no one knows neither. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-clustered size limit is increased from 900 bytes to 1,700 bytes in Azure SQL DB V12 and in the latest SQL 2016 CTP.  Don't ask me why not 1,701 :-)

I can only assume the length restrictions are needed for optimization of internal SQL Server memory structures.